# Reactjs change content in div with onclick from another component

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am new to react and am having trouble with an issue.

I have one component (film.js) that has a map array of objects, and by clicking on each of them I would like to change the {komponentaFilma}  depending on which one of the elements is clicked.

My logic might be totally wrong so feel free to point me in the right direction thank you.

app.js

```
      render() {

    let komponentaFilma = null;
    if ( this.state.prikaziFilmCont ) {
      komponentaFilma = (
        <div className="trailer_container">
          <p>Ovo je film koji je kliknut</p>
        </div>
      );
    }


    return (
      <div>
      <div className="movies-container">
        {this.state.filmovi.map((film, index) => {
          return <Film
                    naslov={film.naslov}
                    naslovnaSlika={film.naslovnaSlika}
                    key={film.id}
                    openFilm={() => this.injectFilm(index)}/>
      })}
      </div>
      <Gallery />
      {komponentaFilma}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

i am also using this method in app.js

```
  injectFilm = (filmIndex) => {
    const prikaziFilm = this.state.prikaziFilmCont;
    this.setState({prikaziFilmCont: !prikaziFilm})
  }
```

this also has

```
prikaziFilmCont: false
```

in the state

film.js looks like this

```
const Film = (props) => {
  return (
      <div onClick={props.openFilm} className="singleMovie">
        <h3>{props.naslov}</h3>
        <img src={props.naslovnaSlika} alt="nova slika "/>
      </div>
  )
}
```

this is the state in my app.js these objects are clicked on, and i would like to pass info from these object (onclick) to komponenta filma.

```
  state = {
    filmovi: [
      {
        "naslov": "Safarikova",
        "id": "00",
        "naslovFilma": "Safarikova",
        "godina": "Safarikova",
        "opis": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ....",
        "naslovnaSlika": "http://dusanmuncan.underconstructioncity.com/srdjan_susa/images/safarikova.png",
        "linkVideo": "http://video/video.mp4",
        "externiLink": "http://www.vimeo.com/video.mp4"
      }, {
        "naslov": "Svetski sampion",
        "id": "01",
        "naslovFilma": "Sampion",
        "godina": "Safarikova",
        "opis": "Cupcake ipsum color sit pinaple juice ....",
        "naslovnaSlika": "http://dusanmuncan.underconstructioncity.com/srdjan_susa/images/trailer_prvaksveta.png",
        "linkVideo": "http://video/videosampoion.mp4",
        "externiLink": "http://www.vimeo.com/videosampion.mp4"
      }, {
        "naslov": "Stolice",
        "id": "02",
        "naslovFilma": "stolicice malene",
        "godina": "stolice ",
        "opis": "sede ljudi na stolicama i na kraju ustanu",
        "naslovnaSlika": "http://dusanmuncan.underconstructioncity.com/srdjan_susa/images/trailer_stolice.png",
        "linkVideo": "http://video/stolice.mp4",
        "externiLink": "http://www.vimeo.com/sto_lice.mp4"
      }
    ],
    prikaziFilmCont: false
  }
```

if you need something more from me please do write.

Comment: when `Flim` component is clicked, you are able to see `komponentaFilma` ? you just want to change `komponentaFilma` according to which `Flim` clicked

Comment: @JSEngine I would like to change the structure of komponentaFilma with different html and also pass the object that is clicked on from the film.js to take other data from that object and show it. 
all data is in app.js in the state.

I have added my state so you can see what I need. when clicked on I need to show data in komponentaFilm from the objects. needs to be differently styled and composed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `selectedFilm` property in your state

```
state: {
  ...... // other properties in state
  selectedFilm: {}
}
```

You need to find which film was clicked and set that film as `selectedFilm` in the state in `App` component. so change in `injectFilm`

```
injectFilm = (filmIndex) => {
    // const prikaziFilm = this.state.prikaziFilmCont;
    // finding the film clicked 
    const selectedFlim = this.state.filmovi.find((film, index) => index === filmIndex)
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        // prikaziFilmCont: !prevState.prikaziFilm,
       selectedFlim
    }))    
  }
```

And you can update your `if` condition and use `selectedFlim`

```
// checking if "selectedFlim" is empty object or not
// if it is not empty then use "komponentaFilma" as below jsx
// otherwise "komponentaFilma" will be null
let komponentaFilma = null;
if ( Object.keys(this.state.selectedFilm).length > 0 ) {
      komponentaFilma = (
        <div className="trailer_container">
          <p>{this.state.selectedFlim.id}</p>
          <p>{this.state.selectedFlim.naslovFilma}</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

And at last you can use `komponentaFilma` in your jsx

```
return (
      <div>
      <div className="movies-container">
        {this.state.filmovi.map((film, index) => {
          return <Film
                    naslov={film.naslov}
                    naslovnaSlika={film.naslovnaSlika}
                    key={film.id}
                    openFilm={() => this.injectFilm(index)}/>
      })}
      </div>
      <Gallery />
      // checking if "selectedFlim" is empty object or not
      // if it is empty then nothing is displayed
      // otherwise "komponentaFilma" will be displayed
      {Object.keys(this.state.selectedFilm).length > 0 && komponentaFilma}
      </div>
    );
```

**Note:** you could use `KomponentaFilma` as component and pass `selectedFilm` as props

eg:

```
{Object.keys(this.state.selectedFilm).length > 0 && <KomponentaFilma selectedFilm={this.state.selectedFilm />}
```

`KomponentaFilma` component could be

```
const KomponentaFilma = ({selectedFilm}) => {
   return (
     <div>
       <p>{selectedFlim.id}</p>
       <p>{selectedFlim.naslovFilma}</p>
     </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: It's my pleasure